# XeLaTeX + fontspec + StylisticSet changes underlying Unicode characters in the text

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode, opentype

I have recently played a bit with OpenType features in some fonts for Insular variants of certain characters – and when I make a document containing characters like `s`, `t`, `g` and set the appropriate feature changing their appearance to the Insular shape, after compiling the PDF when copying the text I get the insular Unicode characters, ie. `ꞅ`, `ꞇ`, `ᵹ`, instead.

I guess this has something to do with the fact that in the fonts those variant shapes are also assigned to those Unicode codepoints (so fontspec doesn’t just change the appearance of the text, but basically changes the underlying text to use them? Or rather chooses the right shapes from the font but in the PDF’s ToUnicode map only maps them to the dedicated Insular codepoints?).

This is annoying as it makes the PDF more difficult to search (using plain s, t, g… doesn’t work).

Is there a way around it, to force the underlying Unicode values to be kept while displaying the alternative shapes?

An example using the Junicode 2.206 font:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in,right=0.8in,left=0.8in,bottom=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[irish]{babel}

\setmainfont{Junicode}[
  ItalicFont={*-Italic},
  Language=Irish,
]

\begin{document}
    \addfontfeature{StylisticSet=2}%
    Aséidir go reiċ os̅ siolla do ċur accoṁḟoc̅ ⁊ ni cóir ni as sía ina sin do cur
    an̅ mͧ atá so leaḋb ⁊ breab ⁊ sgíos ⁊ {\addfontfeature{CharacterVariant=10:4} seng}
    ⁊ geal ⁊ dlúiṫ ⁊ dos ⁊ tioġ Leiḋbreipsgiseingeallútoisdioġ

    As lor liom ꝗ laḃrꝫ de sin.
\end{document}
```

when I compile this with XeLaTeX I get nice Insular letters as expected:
[image]

but when I copy the text back from the PDF, I get:

> Aꞅéidiꞃ ᵹo ꞃeiċ oꞅ̅ ꞅiolla do ċuꞃ accoṁḟoc ⁊ ni cóiꞃ ni aꞅ ꞅía ina ꞅin do cuꞃ an̅ mͧ aꞇá ꞅo leaḋb ⁊ bꞃeab ⁊ ꞅᵹíoꞅ ⁊ ꞅenᵹ ⁊ ᵹeal ⁊ dlúiṫ ⁊ doꞅ ⁊ ꞇioġ Leiḋbꞃeipꞅᵹiꞅeinᵹeallúꞇoiꞅdioġ Aꞅ loꞃ liom ꝗ laḃꞃꝫ de ꞅin.

Instead of expected:

> Aséidir go reiċ os̅ siolla do ċur accoṁḟoc̅ ⁊ ni cóir ni as sía ina sin do cur an̅ mͧ atá so leaḋb ⁊ breab ⁊ sgíos ⁊ seng ⁊ geal ⁊ dlúiṫ ⁊ dos ⁊ tioġ Leiḋbreipsgiseingeallútoisdioġ As lor liom ꝗ laḃrꝫ de sin.

Comment: You can switch to LuaLaTeX, there when setting the fontspec option `Renderer=HarfBuzz` we go through some pain to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, using LuaLaTeX with `\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=HarfBuzz}` indeed works!

Is the problem in XeLaTeX (and LuaLaTeX’s default renderer?) the ToUnicode map and some sort of optimization in the glyphs? (I’m wondering what does choosing HarfBuzz change that makes it work).

Comment: It's complicated... Basically ToUnicode maps map every glyph in the font to some Unicode codepoints. That works as long as each glyph is only used to represent one sequence of codepoints, but in all slightly more complicated situations it inadequate. E.g. in your font the same glyph is used both for `ꞅ` and `s`, so there is no way to define a mapping for the glyph which always maps to the right Unicode string. Also in the PDF the same font (and therefore the same ToUnicode map) is used if the same font is used with different features, so the mapping can't take activated features into account.

Comment: When using LuaLaTeX in harfbuzz mode we try to workaround this issue in the common case that the same glyph is used for multiple codepoints, but only one of them actually appears in the document. This is done by tracking which is the first Unicode sequence the glyph gets used for.

Comment: Once you get e.g. reorderings this gets rather tricky and this leads to the situation that sometimes LuaLaTeX "lies" in the ToUnicode map by basically claiming that the ToUnicode mapping if a glyph is a  completely different glyph, just because the first time the glyph got used it happened to switch positions with the other glyphs in odd places. Now this doesn't lead to actual issues since in HarfBuzz mode LuaLaTeX additionally uses ActualText mappings to individually override ToUnicode mappings in places where the default mappings would not fit the text.

Comment: XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX's Node mode use the simpler route of just providing best effort mappings.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation! I was imagining that whenever a character variant is used a new font entry (with just one glyph or a few, for the variants) get created and that one glyph uses the alternative font with its own ToUnicode mapping. (So my wrong expectation was that using a single font with 5 different stylistic sets/char variants would result in a PDF with ~6 different embedded fonts).

But I see it’s actually handled completely differently.